# NextJS passar um JSON para outra página

Tags: javascript, next.js

Boa tarde! Pessoal estou com uma dúvida e até consegui fazer via Route.Push() porém todos os dados são exibidos na URL da página seguinte.

Um exemplo:

- Tenho uma página com um Login onde passo um CPF/CNPJ e o Codigo do Cliente.
- Ao digitar os dados consulto uma API e em caso de sucesso ele me retorna um JSON com todos os dados desse cliente que necessito. (Tive que usar o JSON.Stringfy() para funcionar)

**Envio dos Dados**

```
fetch(
'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/rest/ponto_facil/cliente?doccliente=${values.documento}&codcliente=${values.codigo}'
    )
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(json => {
      router.push({
        pathname: "/dashboard",
        query: { cliente: JSON.stringify(json.cliente) },
      });      
    })
```

Gostaria de "levar" esse JSON para a página seguinte e utilizar. Consegui apenas via URL e além de poluído o cliente não pode dar um refresh que erros acontecem.

**Recebimento na Outra página**

```
const router = useRouter();
  const {
    query: { cliente },
  } = router;

  const dados = JSON.parse(cliente);
```

Consigo utilizar o array DADOS para criar a página porém todo o conteúdo fica na URL

Existe alguma forma de ao passar o conteúdo não utilizar o QUERY do Router e passar o objeto?

Agradeço as ajudas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse cenário a melhor solução é utilizando o context, dentro do seu context você vai criar um state que ira armazenar o resultado da sua requisição e na página seguinte você só vai precisar acessar esse state.

[Documentação em português explicando o context com mais detalhes](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)